# resample a pandas df within each group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that has a `MultiIndex` of `(id, date)` and I would like to do 2 things:

1. convert the `DateTimeIndex` named `date` to a `PeriodIndex` within each `id` group
2. `resample` the frequency of the `PeriodIndex` to monthly from daily

My current (non-working) method is to (even before converting to `PeriodIndex`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"val": np.arange(30), 
                          "id": np.tile([1,2], 15),
                          "date": np.repeat(pd.date_range(start = "2000-01-01", periods = 15, name="date"), 2)
                         })

df = df.set_index(["id", "date"]).sort_index() 
df.groupby("id")["val"].resample(rule = "M", closed = "right", label = "right").apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(sum(x)/10))
```

This raises:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'
```

What's the right way to do the whole procedure? I'm a bit confused about how to think about `groupby`: my mental model is that anything that follows a `groupby` operation will only receive the subframe corresponding to that group (ie the `MultiIndex` becomes a single index of just `date` within that particular group). Is this not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) is necessary `DatetimeIndex` set before `groupby`, also `apply` is not necessary, faster is `resample` `sum`, then divide final `Series` by 10 and then use `np.sqrt`:

```
df = df.set_index(["date"]).sort_index() 

df1 = (np.sqrt(df.groupby("id")["val"]
                 .resample(rule = "M", closed = "right", label = "right")
                 .sum()
                 .div(10)))

print (df1)
id  date      
1   2000-01-31    4.582576
2   2000-01-31    4.743416
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: please explain: i need to resampling to happen within each group... also if possible comment on the rest of the question

Comment: @Alex - sure, give me some time.

Comment: @Alex - there is `Multiindex` in input `DataFrame`? Or is created by you?

Comment: in the input but it was also created by me at a different point in time and i'm just loading a pickled object. my understanding was that setting `id` and `date` as the two indices was the correct procedure for working with panel data in pandas, no?

Comment: i guess i'm confused about why grouping then sampling is not the right approach...ie for each group i want to resample, so the resampler should get passed each group without the outermost (id) index...

Comment: I think this aproach is good, check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0181-deferred-ops). And `id` is not necessary set to `Multiindex`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172195/discussion-between-alex-and-jezrael).